# How to upload .csv file into tables in Apex?

Tags: mysql, csv, oracle-apex

I have question using Apex 5 for uploading data into tables through csv file format. Using the Data loading wizard, I was able to do it easily for all the columns but I want to know how to do it only for specific columns.

For example, I have a table with three columns `x`, `y`, `z` and I have an Excel sheet with `y` and `z` data. `x` is a foreign key and its value has to be taken from another table. How can I insert only `y` and `z` data with `x` data coming from another table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this all the time, in reality it's simply easiest to import your data to a new table and do a manual merge.
(it's also the fastest)

1. Import your data to a new temporary table (all options open and large values, so no rows will be dropped)
2. Merge / insert your data to the correct table
3. Drop the temporary table.

I was always trying to do a direct insert with non-homogeneous data and simply switching practices, made my life easier.
---  EDIT ----

Explaining the process, importing spreadsheet or CSV data in APEX 5.0

**Select data workshop**

[image: Select data workshop]

**Select data format**

[image: apex 5 import data format]

**New table + copy paste**

[image]

**Copy paste some spreadsheet data**

[image]

**Confirm new table and data**

[image]

**create new sequence**

[image]

Press **Load data**

After that you can open up your favorite sql editor and insert the data using regular DML.

```
select * from STAGING_T1;
```

After you have processed the data, delete the staging table

```
drop table STAGING_T1;
```

Olafur

Comment: Could you send me any reference in how to do it

Answer (score 0):

for similar case i created Data Loading Wizard pages in my application
in wizard

there is a section data lookup which can be used for this need

you can inspect below tutorial in 4.1, probably it would work in 5.0

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r41/dataload/dataload.htm

Comment: Hi thank you very much.for reply.Is there any way to look the Insert Operation source code of the data loading wizard.My case is like i want to insert x value which is same value for set of data upload.Example. i have 20 data for y and z column in a excel sheet,X value is a numeric which i get from another table .For all the 20 data it should insert with that single common x value

Comment: in wizard 3rd page report there is a query for representing the data initial uploaded data as below probably it is uploading csv data to a table named  apex_collections you may modify it with a process between pages

Comment: select n001 as row_num,
       c049 as action,
       c001, c002, c003,
       c004, c005, c006,
       c007, c008, c009,
       c010, c011, c012,
       c013, c014, c015,
       c016, c017, c018,
       c019, c020, c021,
       c022, c023, c024,
       c025, c026, c027,
       c028, c029, c030,
       c031, c032, c033,
       c034, c035, c036,
       c037, c038, c040,
       c041, c042, c043,
       c044, c045
  from apex_collections
 where collection_name = 'LOAD_CONTENT'
   and c049 in ('INSERT','UPDATE', 'FAILED')
 order by seq_id

Comment: Hi,In the Data validation i could able to write process to fill the column based on some expression but my problem is its not getting mapped when i according to column.i want to fill my first column with constant value and rest two columns from Excel sheet.Please give me some example how i can write code to in the column mappping.Example-in the first page i could able to upload excel sheet with two column data and in second page i could able to see two column data.i need to add the first column with empty data or something.how can i achieve this.Please help me if possible @Bahadirs

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that all fields in your database table has data so you you can add a page process for giving new values to the uploaded data which has null x columns

1 go to 4th page 'Data Load Results' which created by data wizard

2 click add a page process button

3 choose pl/sql

4 give a name and choose on submit - after computations and validations

5 enter an update command which suits your needs as below

```
update your_table_name
set 
x=20
where x is null;
```

6 write your success messages

7 choose finish button in option "when button presses"

8 create process

9 add a Branch button in Branches

10 give a name click next

11 enter the page you want to go after data load

12 choose finish button in option "when button presses"

13 go to finish button and choose submit in Action When Button Clicked -> action

by adding this process and branch

1st system will insert data to table

2nd it will update all the null x values to the static values in your table

3rd it will return to the page you want